# Android Development Application Scaling Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

This is probably an easy question to answer or maybe it's just unclear to me from jumping right into development with Android.

I have a phonegap Android app with different mediaquery views on the pages view for tablet and phone sizes.

When I try the emulator I have to select the view of the phone or size so I selected the same size as my app which looks great my problem is with so many Android devices do I have to support all various sizes for my app to function?  Do I need to create some sort of liquid layout?

Is it better to do on ready css `zoom: 75%;` which was is best way to approach this?

When you submit an app to Google Play to you have to pick which device your app is designed for?

I tried submitting an app to the Amazon store and it was rejected multiple times as I have to support Motorola Zoom when I specifically designed the app for the Kindle Fire.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuerymobile? It adapts to all different sizes and you don't have to worry about it. Just make sure the `mobileinit` and `deviceready` events are properly handled

Comment: If you intentionally created a layout that fits a particular screen size, then I am not sure if there is any solution than taking a good gut feel of what is needed and implement. Android (For Google Play) gives you the ability to provide assets for 4 layouts (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi) (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) which are sufficient for all the screens. You may also need to consider the fact that resizing by % (zoom:75%) may create a problem for finger touch operations which expects a 8mmx8mm touch area in general while zooming in.

Answer (score 0):

This is an important question. I think Phonegap/cordova is not yet ready as a high end platform for **professional** app dev.. However there's always hacks that make it work.

My current approach to your question, if you are developping for Android, is;

1. Start creating your design with a size of 320x480 (same as iPhone 3GS), why? check out the google device market share; [Screen Sizes and Densities](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens).
2. I prefer using illustrator as it will allow later to export assets with higher resolution. So later I include images on my app for example, and I don't specify width/height; just let the container decide.
3. My app is inside a global container. When i finish the app I use a script to detect current window size and set **-webkit-transform-origin** & **-webkit-transform** of the global container to fit the screen.
4. Test your app in first in the browser then on real/emulated devices; I suggest Chrome as it has a device emulation panel..

This is a bit hacky but it works as of now..